# java: Date is already defined in this compilation unit

Tags: java

InteliiJ IDE make `Date.java` :

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Date {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }
```

Bug Show

> Error:(2, 1) java: Date is already defined in this compilation unit

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can use `import java.util.Date` and create a class called `Date` at the same time.  I'd change the name of your `Date` class to something else

Comment: The `import` statement conflicts with your class name. Since you are already using `java.util.Date date` to define your `date` variable the import statement can be removed. But I strongly suggest you to use another class name.

Comment: @Vu Phuong Nam: since you declare and instantiate your variable as: java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(); you don't need that import statement. If you remove that, it should work

Comment: @MadProgrammer or he could just remove the import statement. Granted, it might be confusing when considering names, but sometimes other people decide on the names to use.

Comment: @Stultuske Overall, sometimes it's hard to come up with a non-conflicting name, but sometimes, it's just bleedingly obvious, since the class doesn't actually do any "date" functionality, changing it to something more meaningful would probably be the better cause of action

Comment: @MadProgrammer true. then again it is possible that this is just his 'minimal code to reproduce the issue'. For all I know it is an actual Date-type and his requirements say to use that name. Either way, with the code being as is, whether he renames the class or not, he should remove the import statement, since it's not actually useful.

Comment: @Stultuske Naming your classes the same way as some very popular class in standard is a bad idea. Especially from java.lang but most from java.util as well. Imagine someone naming his class `String`. Just don't.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use for example `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @Amongalen I don't disagree with you. but: once I was put on a project to maintain. They even managed to 'rewrite' the Object class. Another time, I worked on a new project where the project leads had decision right on class names, we had to use the name Date for a class, otherwise there would be mapping issues with the partner. It's a bad thing to do, indeed, doesn't mean you won't have to do it now and then (or learn to live with it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class name cannot be the same as any of your imports.

Because is you import `java.util.Date`, then `Date` anywhere in your script implicitely means `java.util.Date`...

Two solutions then :
1. rename your class and you can get rid of the qualifier for uses of Date in your code

```
import java.util.Date;

public class DateMain {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }
}
```

or remove the import

```
public class Date {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }
}
```

HTH :)

Comment: it seems you are missing the obvious. Yes, he can rename his class, but that wouldn't make the import statement any less obsolete. He can also just remove the import statement.

Comment: Quite true @Stultuske. I edited my answer accordingly eventhough I guess the OP had no constraint about his class name and would benefit not having to qualify java.util.Date each time he uses it.

Comment: Thank your help .